# Auto complete the textbox from the oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

```
    void AutoCompleteText()
    {
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        string query = "select * from Book;";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
        OracleDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("Title");
                coll.Add(sName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
    }
```

In the table Book I have a column named Title, I want to suggest me when I'm searching in the textbox1, suppose I write A in the textbox1, then it will automatically pop up all the title starting with A from the Oracle Database.

But by implementing the code I got the following Errors:

Error-1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments

Error-2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: It is telling you that the `GetString()` method is expecting an integer as the argument.  You need to provide the column index of the `Title` column, rather than the column name.

Answer (score 0):

[`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) takes an `int` as an argument. You're trying to pass a `string`. You can use [`GetOrdinal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getordinal.aspx) to get the column ordinal of the named column:

```cs
while (myReader.Read())
{
    string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Title"));
    coll.Add(sName);
}
```

Alternatively, this should work as well:

```cs
string sName = (string) myReader["Title"];
```